# Meaning of "to carbon-tax-and-spend humanity into prosperity and cleanliness"

Tags: meaning

> This happened even before Justin Trudeau, Rachel Notley, and Kathleen Wynne arrived on the scene to carbon-tax-and-spend humanity into prosperity and cleanliness.

This sentence is originally from an article online, I feel there is a gap between "to carbon-tax-and-spend" and "humanity into prosperity and cleanliness"
Is there a need for a verb or something in the middle part?

Comment: It's a political commentary to make individuals and firms pay taxes for emitting carbon (and use the money for your own pet projects) and turn that into giving them a better life (according to Canadian politicians) and live cleaner lives (according to the same).

Comment: *to carbon-tax-and-spend" = ***in order** to carbon-tax-and-spend*. **To carbon-tax-and-spend** is used as a verb infinitive = "to impose carbon taxes and to spend those taxes on public services."

Comment: The base expression you need first is this: tax and spend, a governing philosophy. Here, they have modified the original expression and made it a carbon tax.

Comment: It is edgy political humor. As @Lambie pointed out, the phrase *tax and spend* is a well-known political philosophy. Making it *carbon-tax and spend* plays with that concept, making it humorous.

Answer (score 1):

The writer has condensed the phrase *carbon tax and spend* (a variation of the familiar phrase in political argument "tax and spend", as one of the comments points out) into a single verb *carbon-tax-and-spend*.

So the infinitive clause is *to X humanity into prosperity and cleanliness*, where X is the nonce-verb *carbon-tax-and-spend*.

("Nonce" here means "made up for the purpose")